# How to use links of REST API with HATEOAS using JS?

Tags: javascript, rest, github-api, hateoas

I study REST API and I found out that communication with GitHub API should start with root request which returns links to most essential resources:

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/meta/meta?apiVersion=2022-11-28

This practice aligns with HATEOAS principle which gives client possibility to send request without hard coding or modification of URI's.

But here is the thing:

`https://api.github.com/search/users?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}`

I don't understand how can I fetch it without modification? HATEOAS trying to make client-server communication loosely coupled.
Am I missing something?

Best variant that I found:

```js
const baseURI = "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q={query}";

const searchQuery = 'your-search-query';
const endpoint = baseURI.replace('{query}', encodeURIComponent(searchQuery));

fetch(endpoint).then(res => res.json());
```

But as a client I definitely have to know exact URI to change it in the appropriate way. And if I need to use this request in multiple places I have to repeat this process. Or change all links that I got from the root request. But the URI template could be more complicated, so this is not a variant.

Comment: The GitHub API returns something like a _template_ for some links. You are correct that you have to modify the returned link to do an actual request. That means you have to know what the parameters in the template mean.

Comment: @rveerd, but what's the point of using HATEOAS principle? I mean, in further request when I get resource and URIs of associated resources it's awesome. At least if API return relations with inserted id's or queries or whatsoever should be in place of URI template. But if API returns links with template it's broken. Maybe there is an appropriate response format that regulates links with params? I didn't find anything about using links with params in HAL or JSON:API

Comment: You often have to deviate from theory and principles to build a practical solution.

Comment: I just want to understand deeply what is REST and when it is profitable

Comment: This is a Templated Link, and they *do* appear in HAL as well. The format is a URI Template.